# Pesquisa Base de Dados em PHP

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, table, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu tenho um base de dados com 3 tabelas e preciso de saber se na tabela A (por exemplo) o campo **tipo** for 0 vai buscar dados à tabela B, se for 1 vai buscar dados à tabela C.

E tenho o seguinte código que já vinha no site (quando peguei nele), e dá erro :

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

```
 <?php
 include("connection.php");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

 <tbody aria-live='polite' aria-relevant='all'>";
  $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT lugar,dorsal as id,tipo as classe from classificacao where tipo2=70");
  while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
   if($row3['classe'] == 0){
    $result8 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT r.nome, r.equipa from registo r where id=r.Dorsal and classe = 0");
    while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result8)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row3['lugar'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row3['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['nome'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>-</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row4['equipa'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
   }
   else{
    $result9 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT f.nome, f.n_federado, f.equipa from registofederados f where id=f.Dorsal and classe = 1");
    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9)){//linha 345
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row3['lugar'] . "</td>"; 
         echo "<td>" . $row3['id'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row5['nome'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row5['n_federado'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row5['equipa'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
  }
 }
 echo "</tbody>
</table>
</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `<tbody aria-live='polite' aria-relevant='all'>";` Seu código está com erro de sintaxe. Não misture PHP com HTML.

Comment: Esse código está uma confusão...

Comment: @JorgeB. Pois está mas foi assim que eu peguei nele..

Comment: @BrunoGibellino o que está a acontecer é que a pesquisa não está a retornar nada.

Comment: Tens dados na tabela `registofederados`?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim tenho apenas um dado

Comment: com `classe = 1` ?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim tudo o que for federado é classe 1

Comment: mas tens algum registo com `classe = 1` no banco?

Comment: Em todos os `mysqli_query()` antes do ponto e virgula, adicione, `die(mysqli_error($con));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atenção que tu na tua consulta SQL estava mal e estavas a escrever HTML dentro do PHP! 
Tenta assim:

```
 <?php
 include("connection.php");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
 ?>
 <tbody aria-live='polite' aria-relevant='all'>;
 <?php
  $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT lugar,dorsal,tipo as classe from classificacao where tipo2=70");
  while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){
      $dorsal = $row3["dorsal"];
   if($row3['classe'] == 0){
$result8 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT r.nome, r.equipa from registo r   where id=" . $dorsal . " and classe = 0");
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result8)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row3['lugar'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row3['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row4['nome'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>-</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row4['equipa'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
   }
   else{
    $result9 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT f.nome, f.n_federado, f.equipa from registofederados f where id=" . $dorsal . " and classe = 1");
while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row3['lugar'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row3['id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row5['nome'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row5['n_federado'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row5['equipa'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
  }
 }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Continua a dar erro Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercicios\OxygenTarget\php\verregistosA.php on line 345

Comment: que erro é que esta a dar desta vez?

Comment: A linha 345 neste trecho de código é a linha...

Comment: Já adicionei ao código um comentario indicando a linha de erro

Comment: Tenta Agora sff

Comment: Continua a dar o mesmo erro. Eu sou novo na ligação php e sql,  e mesmo em php em si. Pode me dizer o que aquele erro é?

Comment: pelo que sei é a query que está a retornar um false..

Comment: tentou usar o mysql_fetch_array()?

Comment: Tente a seguinte solução: http://pastebin.com/VScUCt8Z    - Apontei alguns erros também, como observação.